# Why is Python changing case during json read and text write?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 where I am reading a json file with sample data as below:

```
{
    "ip_list": {
        "sensitive": false,
        "type": "list",
        "value": [
            {
                        "node1" : "10.0.0.1",
                        "node2" : "10.0.0.2",
                        "node0" : "10.0.0.3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "key_name": {
        "sensitive": false,
        "type": "string",
        "value": "dataengineer-Ohio-Dev"
    }
}
```

My sample code to read the file is:

```
def main():

  with open('/tmp/json.out') as output_file:
    vData = json.load(output_file)

  vKeyName = vData['key_name']['value']
  print vData['key_name']['value']

Output: dataengineer-ohio-dev
```

For some reasons, the output is showing me only lower case instead of actual data.
Is that expected behavior? Is there any way I can get the output same as my input?
Please give some suggestions.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: What do you mean "instead of actual data", especially "instead of lower case"??

Comment: Also, **always** use the generic [python] tag

Comment: it's hard to figure out what you are doing... like for me when I run this it works as expected...

Comment: That sounds like you did something weird somewhere you're not showing us. Maybe you're opening the wrong file, or you called `lower` somewhere, or you're running different code from what you think you're running.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so that we aren't making assumptions about parts of the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: (to be clear, part of a good MCVE is that it's *actively tested* that someone else can reproduce the issue from the code given, without needing anything that isn't included in the question itself -- ie. unprovided files/variables/etc; otherwise, it isn't "complete" or "verifiable").

Comment: ...one way to check whether your code is actually a MCVE is to try running it in an online interpreter such as http://ideone.com/.